# htaccess mod_rewrite - beginners question

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Lets say I have one file like index.php that needs to process a url like this:

```
index.php?cat=1&sub=2&id=3
```

Now I want to have nice urls for that, which will look like:

```
index.php/cars/bmw/x3
```

My question is, if the word 'cars' is the name in the database associated with the 'cat/category' id of 1, when i go to index.php/cars, how does the url access the database, find 'cars', grab it's corresponding id of '1', and map it to the url?

this site is in Php / MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .htaccess file inside DocumentRoot of your webserver place this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php/cars/(.+)$ /index.php?carName=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

That will call your index.php with whatever comes after /cars/ in the URL with the query parameter carName.

Then inside your index.php write a MySQL query to query the database, something like: select * from cars_table where name=$_REQUEST["carName"]; and you will be able to retrieve the matching car record.

However just as a caution SQL like above are subject to SQL injection attack so it is better to use prepared sql statement or [Mysqli exetnsion of php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for querying the DB instead of directly putting http request value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) directive

[This page](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=175944) has an example similar to your need.